# Gamma Type Integral

Tags: integration, functions, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, gamma-function

I was hoping someone could help me with a question I came across recently: essentially it's a gamma type integral that your asked to evaluate/reduce:

P=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{cx^{4}}{4}}dx$

where c is a constant. The way your asked to evaluate it is to reduce the integrand using a taylor expansion to order 1 for the exponential function and then use the fact that

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}$

I can't come to any plausible solutions to this problem. I mean you could say that 
$e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{cx^{4}}{4}}\approx1-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{cx^{4}}{4}+\dots$

but to order 1 this would just result in the integrand becoming 1 and this doesn't make sense? If the question said using the exponential to order 2 then the integral would evaluate to $\sqrt{2\pi}$ and thus P itself would be 1 but my thoughts are that the reduced P is wanted in terms of c? Can someone please provide some guidance or a possible way to reduce P. Thanks very much.

Comment: Where did this integral come from?

Comment: Hi Mhenni, it's a question that I was asked to solve recently in a maths quiz. I couldn't solve it at the time and it's been bugging me because I know it's not that difficult, but at the same time I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm not even sure if I have the right approach. Like I said in the question any help or guidance would be much appreciated or even alternative approaches?? Obviously some kind of Taylor expansion is needed as the integral P by itself does not exist.

Comment: Note that Taylor expansion approach does not work for this integral as the antiderivative of the Taylor expansion cannot substitute $x=\infty$ and $x=-\infty$ .

Answer (score 4):

Note that this integral converges when $\text{Re}(c)\geq0$ .

When $c=0$ , the question is provided.

I only able to solve the case of positive real number $c$ :

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{cx^4}{4}}~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{cx^4}{4}}~dx+\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{cx^4}{4}}~dx\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_\infty^0e^{-\frac{(-x)^2}{2}-\frac{c(-x)^4}{4}}~d(-x)+\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{cx^4}{4}}~dx\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{cx^4}{4}}~dx+\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{cx^4}{4}}~dx\right)$

$=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{cx^4}{4}}~dx$

$=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2(2+cx^2)}{4}}~dx$

$=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\bigl(\frac{\sqrt2\sinh x}{\sqrt c}\bigr)^2\bigl(2+c\bigl(\frac{\sqrt2\sinh x}{\sqrt c}\bigr)^2\bigr)}{4}}~d\biggl(\dfrac{\sqrt2\sinh x}{\sqrt c}\biggr)$

$=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{c\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\sinh^2x(2+2\sinh^2x)}{2c}}\cosh x~dx$

$=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{c\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\sinh^2x\cosh^2x}{c}}\cosh x~dx$

$=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{c\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\sinh^22x}{4c}}\cosh x~dx$

$=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{c\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\cosh4x-1}{8c}}\cosh x~dx$

$=\dfrac{e^\frac{1}{8c}}{2\sqrt{c\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\cosh4x}{8c}}\cosh x~d(4x)$

$=\dfrac{e^\frac{1}{8c}}{2\sqrt{c\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\cosh x}{8c}}\cosh\dfrac{x}{4}dx$

$=\dfrac{e^\frac{1}{8c}}{2\sqrt{c\pi}}K_\frac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{8c}\right)$

In fact this is a special case of the result of $\int_0^\infty e^{-(ax^2+b)(cx^2+d)}~dx$ provided in http://pi.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/IntegralsDefinite/DefInt.html.

Please feel free to edit my answer if you are able to handing the case of complex number $c$ .

Comment: Hi Harry - thanks for the solution. I just have one question: is there a reason for the inspired substitution about 7 lines into the answer i.e $x=\frac{\sqrt{2}sinh(x)}{\sqrt{c}}$

Comment: @user96007: The main reasons are that $1+\sinh^2x=\cosh^2x$ and having the $\infty$ upper or lower limits, hyperbolic functions substitutions is more preferable than trigonometric functions substitutions.

Comment: How about handing the case of complex number $c$ ? Applying the above procedure to the case of complex number $c$ should not work since the upper limit after transformation is no more as $\infty$ .

Comment: You can simply use analytic continuation in $c$ to extend the equality to $\Re c \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an elementary integral and I do not know how it can be on a math quiz! Here is a solution

> $${\frac {{{\rm e}^{1/(8c)}}{{\rm K}_{1/4}\left(1/(8c)\right)}}{2\sqrt {c\,
> \pi }}},$$

where $K_a(x)$ is the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: Thanks for the solution Mhenni, can I ask how you arrived at it i.e what approximations were made for the integrand and what steps reduced the integral to a Bessel function?

Comment: +1. I actually very much like this example and I think it should be worked out by every physicist before learning anything on perturbation theory.

Comment: So, perhaps it was a mistake on the quiz.  Or maybe there was some wording like: for what values $c$ does this integral converge.  Or perhaps it was a differential equations course that had recently done a DE with solution $K_a$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Or perhaps one of the possible reasons of this question happening on the quiz is that to examine students the knowledge of relating this integral to bessel functions.